# Verifying a Linear transformation from M 2,2 -> R

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to verify whether or not the function:

```
T:M(2,2) -> R, T(A) = a + b - c + d, where A =
```

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

From what I understand, T(v) = Av is a linear transformation and thus I need to prove this from my given function. However I don't know how to go about doing this. I also know that there are two properties of linear transformations:

```
T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)
T(cu) = cT(u)
```

But again, I'm lost how to verify this "linear transformation" from matrix to R.

Comment: There's no $T(v)=Av$ here. You're confused about something, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: That would be a theorem for the linear transformation Given by a Matrix. I'm confused because that is the linear transformation given by a matrix but I'm asked to prove a linear transformation from a matrix to R

Comment: Matrices have a natural correspondence to linear maps, however, the matrix $A$ you have here is not being looked at as a linear map. Instead of that matrix it could just as easily have been the vector $(a+b-c+d)$.

Comment: *vector $(a,b.c,d)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U = \begin{bmatrix}u_{11}&u_{12}\\u_{21}&u_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

$V = \begin{bmatrix}v_{11}&v_{12}\\v_{21}&v_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

$U+V = \begin{bmatrix}u_{11}+v_{11}&u_{12}+v_{12}\\u_{21}+v_{21}&u_{22}+v_{22}\end{bmatrix}$

$T(U+V) = u_{11}+v_{11}+u_{12}+v_{12}-u_{21}-v_{21}+u_{22}+v_{22}$ = T(U)+T(V)

Now show that $T(cU) = cT(U)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I appreciate you allowing me to figure out the other validation on my own.

Answer (score 2):

To show that something is a linear transformation, we want to show that
$$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$$
$$T(cv)=cT(v)$$
Which is exactly what you have mentioned.

So, let $u=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} $ and $v=\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix} $

$$T(u+v)=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a+e&b+f\\c+g&d+h\end{bmatrix} \right)=a+e+b+f-c-g+d+h=(a+b-c+d)+(e+f-g+h)=T(u)+T(v)$$

$$T(kv)=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}k\cdot a&k\cdot b\\k\cdot c&k\cdot d\end{bmatrix} \right)=ka+kb-kc+kd=k(a+b-c+d)=kT(v)$$

Comment: Thank you for the thorough solution. This makes much more sense to me now.