# Expressing a $2\times 2$ matrix as a single equation.

Tags: linear-transformations

From another question ([Verifying a Linear transformation from M 2,2 -> R](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717846/verifying-a-linear-transformation-from-m-2-2-r)) I saw the following proof which shows that
$$T(kv)=kT(v)$$
$$T(kv)=T\left(\begin{bmatrix}k\cdot a&k\cdot b\\k\cdot c&k\cdot d\end{bmatrix} \right)=ka+kb-kc+kd=k(a+b-c+d)=kT(v)$$
But I am wondering exacly what property of matrices gives this equality? $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}k\cdot a&k\cdot b\\k\cdot c&k\cdot d\end{bmatrix} \right)=ka+kb-kc+kd$$
Would the example below also be true?
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\5&7\\\end{bmatrix} = 1+3-5+7 = 6$$

Comment: It's not a property of matrices, it's the definition of the transformation $T$.  In your final equation you have omitted the application of $T$ on the left side, leaving you with something nonsensical; if you added $T( \ldots)$ on the left, then the equation would be true (according to the definition of $T$)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've slightly misunderstood the other question.

$T:M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a map from the vector space $(M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}), +, \cdot, \boldsymbol{0}, \mathbf{I}, \mathbb{R})$ to its scalar field $\mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$T : \begin{bmatrix} a &b \\c &d\end{bmatrix} \mapsto a+b-c+d$$

The previous question asks whether this map is a linear form (a.k.a. a covector). A linear form must satisfy linearity, *i.e.* for all $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, and for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$,

1. $T(\mathbf{A}) + T(\mathbf{B}) = T(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})$
2. $kT(\mathbf{A}) = T(k\mathbf{A})$

This transformation does satisfy the above criteria, and so is a linear form.

This, however, is not due to any property of matrices (indeed, $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$, and so each of these matrices can be replaced with a Cartesian vector) but instead the definition of $T$.

In your example, it is true that

$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\5&7\\\end{bmatrix}\right) = 1+3-5+7 = 6$$